# Why does Docker Desktop on M1 require Rosetta if it uses QEMU for emulation?

Tags: docker, qemu, apple-m1

When installing Docker Desktop for Apple Silicon, the [official instructions](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/install/) says:

> You must install Rosetta 2 as some binaries are still Darwin/AMD64.

However, if I understand correctly, Intel-based containers actually [use QEMU for emulation rather than Rosetta](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/):

> However, attempts to run Intel-based containers on Apple Silicon machines under emulation can crash as qemu sometimes fails to run the container.

(This is one of the reasons why Docker is [slow when running non-native containers on M1](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=25449561).)

So what does Docker actually use Rosetta for?

Comment: Rosetta is for AMD64 binaries of Docker itself, QEMU is for running the *containers*

Comment: @Martheen your comment seems to be the actual answer

Answer (score 2):

Rosetta was used to run Docker itself but according to the [release notes](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/release-notes/), since version 4.3.0:

> Docker Desktop on Apple silicon no longer requires Rosetta 2.

There is two exceptions in the [known issues](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/troubleshoot/known-issues/):

> Some command line tools do not work when Rosetta 2 is not installed.
>
> - The old version 1.x of docker-compose. Use Compose V2 instead.
> - The docker-credential-ecr-login credential helper.

For containers, qemu is used but there is an [open issue](https://github.com/docker/roadmap/issues/384) to run x86-64 containers with Rosetta.

To run x86-64 containers on Apple M1, you can install a x86-64 version of [podman](https://podman.io/) an run it with Rosetta.

Comment: [Colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/blob/fdc6c23dd7cf041de1b2ff3e16de0f2bdb960f37/embedded/defaults/colima.yaml#L113) supports rosetta as well.